# make border-radius clip absolute position layers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make border-radius clip absolute position layers?

http://jsfiddle.net/63qr9/1/

I know in this example these divs do no need to be absolute, but in my application they do and I when it scrolls I need the outer div to mask all inside divs, even if they are positioned absolute.

How could I make this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: It appears to already do that in IE9. What browsers are you seeing it not clip in (I'm guessing Chrome, because I believe there is a bug in that browser regarding border-radius clipping).

Comment: yep chrome, safari, mobile safari